# Rails: Access user from session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've changed my `session_store` to be able to share across subdomains.  I use Devise for user management and When I look at the cookies I see something like:

```
_my_app_session = 3b9dcd63583ec6701a27b9eefa8a26b4
```

where the value is the session ID.  How do I use this value to know who is signed into the website?

Comment: I have not tried this myself, can you check this ? `User.find(session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0])`

Comment: I'm not even sure how to use that

Comment: I believe, if you have a controller, just put `pry` in one of action and try that line. Also, if you're using recent version of devise it should be `User.find(session["warden.user.user.key"][0][0])`

Comment: I'm still confused.  I would like to use this in the `SessionsController`

Comment: Are you trying to check, if the session is already there for the user ? then you can put that in before_action and if you find the user, then redirect him to your desired page; otherwise take him to the log in page.

Comment: I am attempting to share session variables across subdomains and don't want to force users to sign in on both subdomains

Comment: You can't really get a user id from just the session id. The session identifier is just a secret held by both the client and server which is used to both verify that the session storage is still valid and link it to a specific client. The actual claim (the id) is stored in the session storage (another cookie) and you can access it through the session or through warden. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-id